# Passing String value to SQL bigint column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Given following Statment:

```
 String query = "Select * from T_spareParts where SparePartPK IN (? )"
```

In my BackBean (`JSF 2`) I first iterate through all cars in table and build a String of all the cars currently selected (by picking each cars ID as primary key) so the final String before being passed to SQL could look like:

```
String finalString = " '1','2','3','4'";
```

And then :

```
this.prepareStatement= this.connection.prepareStatement(query);
this.prepareStatement.setString(1,finalString);
this.prepareStatement.executeQuery();
```

Exception thrown is:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.
```

Now my understanding is that exception is due to `SparePartPK` is type `bigint` and we're passing a String .

But in SQL Server (2008) i can do :

```
 Select * from T_spareParts where SparePartPK IN ('1','2','3','4')"
```

which returns results as expected. Why am i getting the exception and how can i correct the issue? (also feel free to comment if this isn't the best approach)

### Update:

I've also tried to produce the `finalString`  without single quotes which causes the same exception to be thrown :

```
String finalString = " 1,2,3,4";
```

Comment: Try to remove single quotes from the set.

Comment: @AVD - just tried your suggestion - Exact same Exception thrown .

Comment: can you use put the finastring within prepareStatement and not using parameter setString ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. Though as an alternative I created a `StoredProcedure` where it takes one parameter and inside the StoredProcedure i run the above Query in question formulating the `IN` section using the passed parameter .

So all above code still applies, The parameter passed to the storeDProcedure is one String separated by `,` without the single quotes.

Might not be the optimum answer but works quit well :) .

Comment: I'm sure that some folks would disagree with me, but I try to stay away from stored procs, using them only when absolutely necessary.

Stored procedure languages are not portable - almost every database that supports stored procs has a different stored proc language. If you use a stored proc, and later need to switch to a different database, you have to re-write the stored proc, while the prepared statement will work across all databases.

For a small hobby project, I suppose it wouldn't matter, but for 'real' development, it frequently does.

Comment: i see your point - We've just moved to a new SQL Server and generally they like to run all things Microsoft in current company i work for so chances of moving to a different database environment is highly unlikely. Thanks for pointing it out though, i will keep it in mind in future cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the numbers into an array (not a string), and use preparedStatement.setArray()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the String to type long[] and tried to set up the prepareStatement using `this.prepareStatement.setObject(1,testArray)` but get an exception error `Driver does not support this function. setObject(1,class [J)`. I am not allowed to change the JDBC drivers we use....